# Auto create share this content from paragraph

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm trying to automate content linking from text to share this…

there are 20 posts on each page that will need to be linked, i.e. why I've done #tweet01

this is my stub, but i think i'm missing something, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
<p id="tweet01">When I was 10 I started washing cars. I then offered to clear paths for those without cars. I soon made money from most houses on my street.</p>

  <div class="stream-item-footer">
    <ul class="tweet-actions">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var tweet = $("#tweet01").text()
            var shortTweet = $("#tweet01").text()    // get the text within the div
            .trim()    // remove leading and trailing spaces
            .substring(0, 100)    // get first 100 characters
            .split(" ") // separate characters into an array of words
            .slice(0, -1)    // remove the last full or partial word
            .join(" ") + "..."; // combine into a single string and append "..."
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $().html('<li><span class="st_twitter" st_url="http://www.domain.com" st_title="'+ ++shortTweet +'"></span></li>');
                    $().html('<li><span class="st_linkedin" st_url="http://www.domain.com" st_title="'+ ++tweet +'" st_summary="'+ ++tweet +'"></span></li>');
                    $().html('<li><span class="st_facebook" st_url="http://www.domain.com" st_title="'+ ++tweet +'" st_summary="'+ ++tweet +'"></span></li>');
                    $().html('<li><span class="st_googleplus" st_url="http://www.domain.com" st_title="'+ ++tweet +'" st_summary="'+ ++tweet +'"></span></li>');
            });
        </script>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: `$().html('');` doesn't do anything.  `$()` selects nothing, so that's what gets returned.

Comment: Just some advice, instead of putting this code after each tweet, only write this code once.  Give each tweet the same class, then do `$('.tweet').each(function(){  //...  });`.

Comment: Hi Rocket thanks, basically i'm a real ammeter at jquery and this is a merge of a bunch of code i found, i'm trying to print (if i were using php) the code with tweet and shortTweet inserted respecively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do here is move this code to the top of your page, and have it run when the page is ready.  Then what you want to do is, loop through each tweet (after giving them all the same class), and append to its respective `.tweet-actions`.

Like this:

```
<p id="tweet01" class="tweet">When I was 10 I started washing cars. I then offered to clear paths for those without cars. I soon made money from most houses on my street.</p>
<div class="stream-item-footer">
    <ul class="tweet-actions"></ul>
</div>

<p id="tweet02" class="tweet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eleifend pharetra risus non facilisis. Sed sagittis, felis vel viverra metus.</p>
<div class="stream-item-footer">
    <ul class="tweet-actions"></ul>
</div>

<p id="tweet03" class="tweet">Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet flank shoulder pork chop, turducken shankle strip steak capicola biltong jerky. Salami filet mignon short ribs pork chop.</p>
<div class="stream-item-footer">
    <ul class="tweet-actions"></ul>
</div>
```

Then, at the top of your page add this script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.tweet').each(function () {
            var tweet = $(this).text();
            var shortTweet = tweet // get the text within the div
            .trim() // remove leading and trailing spaces
            .substring(0, 100) // get first 100 characters
            .split(" ") // separate characters into an array of words
            .slice(0, -1) // remove the last full or partial word
            .join(" ") + "..."; // combine into a single string and append "..."
            var $actions = $(this).next('.stream-item-footer').find('.tweet-actions');

            $actions.append('<li><span class="st_twitter" st_url="http://www.domain.com" st_title="' + shortTweet + '">Twitter</span></li>');
            $actions.append('<li><span class="st_linkedin" st_url="http://www.domain.com" st_title="' + tweet + '" st_summary="' + tweet + '">LinkedIn</span></li>');
            $actions.append('<li><span class="st_facebook" st_url="http://www.domain.com" st_title="' + tweet + '" st_summary="' + tweet + '">Facebook</span></li>');
            $actions.append('<li><span class="st_googleplus" st_url="http://www.domain.com" st_title="' + tweet + '" st_summary="' + tweet + '">Google+</span></li>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/XHgtg/